# How to detect if XML has a tag and then to add it as innerHTML with JS?

Tags: javascript, xml

In my XML there are some items that have a description tag, while others do not. I would like to display all the items as blog posts, but the description on them should be shown only if it is included.

When I loop through the items, as soon as it detects an item with no description tag, the code breaks. Thus only the first 3 items are displayed on my website, as they have a description but the 4th item does not.

I have tried the if statement in many ways but can't get it to work. Here's what I am working with:

```
loadXMLFeed = () => {
  const url =
    'https://myurl.rss';
  fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((data) => {
      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let xml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'application/xml');
      loadContent(xml);
    });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadXMLFeed);

function loadContent(x) {
  let list = document.getElementById('item');
  let item = x.getElementsByTagName('item');
  let itemNum = x.getElementsByTagName('item').length;

  for (let i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'listItem';

    li.innerHTML = `
      <h3>${item[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML}</h3>
      <p>${item[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].innerHTML}</p>
    `;

    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to fix this, using this code:

```
function loadContent(x) {
  let list = document.getElementById('item');
  let item = x.getElementsByTagName('item');
  let itemNum = x.getElementsByTagName('item').length;

  for (let i = 0; i < itemNum; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement('li');
    li.className = 'listItem';

    let title = (li.innerHTML = `
      <h3>${item[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML}</h3>
    `);

    if (item[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0]) {
      li.innerHTML =
        title +
        `<p>${item[i].getElementsByTagName('description')[0].innerHTML}</p>`;
    }

    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```